# Retrieve column name of last month of transactions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe formatted the following way:

```
id | name | 052017 | 062017 | 072017 | 092017 | 102017

20 | abcd |  0     | 100    | 200    | 50     | 0
```

I need to retrieve the column name of the last month an organization had any transactions. In this case, I would like to add a column called "date_string" that would have 092017 as its contents.

Any way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`replace` 0 to `np.nan` then using `last_valid_index`

```
df.replace(0,np.nan).apply(lambda x :x.last_valid_index(),1)
Out[602]: 
0     092017 
dtype: object

#df['newcol'] = df.replace(0,np.nan).apply(lambda x :x.last_valid_index(),1)
```